# ABAQUS: Balancing a thin plate by two fixtures on edge centres under self weight

Tags: finite-element-analysis, abaqus

I've created a plate of dimensions(200x200x5mm). Density=5000.
The plate is inclined at 30 degrees with x axis. 
Now, just under the influence of self weight, the plate is put in equilibrium using two supports at the midpoints of the faces shown in fig.
What gravitational force value (+1 or +9.81) and boundary conditions should be used to get the ideal reaction forces of mgsin30 and mgcos30 at the supports.

PS: I've just fixed(encaster) the plate at the two midpoints of the faces and run the simulation in (Static,General). I've got the reaction forces to be 6.15 & 4.02 N (for g=+10 in x direction). But ideally the normal forces acting on the body must be mgcos30 and mgsin30.

Help me with the boundary conditions and anything that went wrong in the above process. Thank You  [Figure: The two midpoints are circled in the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q44Z.png)

Comment: the bc should not be encastre at both points.  Make 1 encastre and one just ux,uy , and add a uy at the upper corner to prevent out of plane rotation (Assuming a 3d analysis).  If you get it right the reaction force *vector* should be *exactly* zero in the `z` direction.

Comment: Also your hand calculation is wrong. The `x` reactions should obviously add to the total weight.